# Angle between diagonals of a rectangle

Tags: rectangles, angle

[image: Rectangle]

I have both of an rectangle and want to find angle between diagonals of a rectangle (angles `α`, `β`)

I've found the following Math formulas:

`α = 2δ`, where `sin δ = a/d`, where `d = Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b))`

but I can't put it all together cause of I know only `sin δ`, but `δ` is needed in the first formula.

That's how it should calculate it: [OmniCalculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/diagonal-of-rectangle).
For example, for sides **12** and **4** - angle between diagonals is **143.13**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following values:

```
tanδ = (a/2) / (b/2)
δ = atan(a/b) -> tan inverse

tan = (b/2) / (a/2)
 = atan(b/a) -> tan inverse

2 + α = π
2δ + β = π
```

You can calculate as such:

```js
function getDiagonalAngles(a, b) {
  let δ = Math.atan(a / b),
     = Math.atan(b / a),
    α = Math.PI - 2 * δ,
    β = Math.PI - 2 * 

    return {
      "α": α * 180 / Math.PI,
      "β": β * 180 / Math.PI
    }
}

console.log(getDiagonalAngles(12, 4))
console.log(getDiagonalAngles(12, 12))
```